# Implement friendly URLs with product name

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, friendly-url

I'm currently working on an e-commerce site with the following URL format for individual products:

examplesite.com/shop.php?sec=prod&prod=373

Where 373 is an individual product number.  I would like to rewrite all the product URLs so they look like this:

examplesite.com/product-name-here

Unfortunately, some of the product names contain characters such as *, / and !, which should not be included in the URL.

I have access to everything, but limited skills, so please just assume I'm completely naive if you answer!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Using only unique slugs ('product-name-here') could be tricky sometimes. It's better to have something like this:

```
examplesite.com/373/product-name-here.html // or
examplesite.com/373-product-name-here
```

... or any other combination, but keep the product ID in the url. To create slugs, google for `PHP slug generator`

If you're running your server with Apache, you need to load the mod_rewrite module and add an .htaccess to the root of your project (there where you execute the index.php)

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

# examplesite.com/373/product-name-here.html
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9+-_\.])\.html$ shop.php?sec=prod&prod=$1
```

Comment: Hi Claudio, thanks for answering! I found a good site on slug generation (http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator) but I'm unsure where I'd enter this code.  Would this, coupled with the htaccess above, do the job?  Or am I missing some stages out?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You need to generate a slug for each product you have. Most of the time, I save it in the database (I have a field slug in the products table), but you could also generate it on the fly when you're creating the links: `<a href="<?=createSlug($product->title)?>"><?=$product->title?></a>`. In PHP you need to create url's like this one `examplesite.com/373-product-name-here` and the rules in .htaccess are going to catch them and parse into your original url (`shop.php?sec=prod&prod=$1`)

Comment: Check out this tuts: http://www.wjunction.com/13-tutorials-guides/130825-how-create-friendly-urls-your-httaccess-file.html and http://surefirewebservices.com/tutorials/friendly-url-tutorial-pt1